# Canvas setTransform() cuts image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a digit drawing tool that uses the `setTransform()` function to distort/skewer a given digit drawn by the user and download them. Currently, the images seem to have not been cleared out of the frame before a new image is drawn on the canvas.

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image: Meant to be a digit 1, looks like a previous '0' was not erased]

Target:
[image: A digit 1 without marks]

Here is the code related to manipulating the image and downloading it:

```
function save(number) {
    for(let i = -0.2; i <= 0.2; i += 0.05) {
        for(let j = -0.2; j <= 0.2; j += 0.05) {
            for(let k = 0.9; k <= 1.05; k += 0.05){
                for(let l = 0.9; l <= 1.05; l += 0.05){
                    temp2canvas.getContext('2d').setTransform(k, i, j, l, 0, 0);

                    temp2canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, temp2canvas.width, temp2canvas.height);
                    tempcanvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, tempcanvas.width, tempcanvas.height);

                    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";

                    temp2canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 10, 10, 102, 102);
                    tempcanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(temp2canvas, 0, 0, temp2canvas.width, temp2canvas.height, 0, 0, 28, 28);

                    var dataURL = tempcanvas.toDataURL();
                    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
                    zip.file(number + "\\" + count + ".png", document.getElementById("canvasimg").src.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""), {base64: true});
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function done() {
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
    .then(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "data.zip");
    });
}
```

I use the [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) libraries to save files as zips and download them.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform is still active when you call `clearRect()` so the clearing rectangle is itself transformed and may not cover the whole area of the canvas.

Simply reset the transformation matrix to the identity matrix before clearing your canvas:

```js
function save(number) {
    const ctx = temp2canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
    for(let i = -0.2; i <= 0.2; i += 0.05) {
        for(let j = -0.2; j <= 0.2; j += 0.05) {
            for(let k = 0.9; k <= 1.05; k += 0.05){
                for(let l = 0.9; l <= 1.05; l += 0.05){
                    // reset to identity matrix
                    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
                    // clear everything
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, temp2canvas.width, temp2canvas.height);
                    // now set the new matrix
                    ctx.setTransform(k, i, j, l, 0, 0);

                    ctx.fillText( number, 20, 20 );
                    temp2canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                      document.body.appendChild(new Image())
                        .src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
save(1);
```

```html
<canvas id="temp2canvas" width="50" height="50"></canvas><br>
```